# Drupal 7 Teaser Image Block - no titles or other data

Tags: views, media, nodes

I am setting up a pretty straightforward Durpal 7 site, so I am trying to keep things simple. I have an image gallery set up just fine. On the home page, I am trying to set up a block that simply displays 4 random thumbnails from the gallery. I only want the thumbnail images, but I currently also have the image titles, date posted, and posted by data. Is there a simple way to post only the thumbnails and not the other associated data? I have tried to strip down the teaser view to the bare bones, but still the other data are viewable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing the content with a view mode of Teaser, rather show fields, and only the image field.

[image]

[image]

If you want to continue using content with a view mode, install and use [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds)